# Behavior of variable creation inside bash function

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I am using the function below to increment an outside script. The main purpose of this is just to return some data from ifconfig and ping test outputs. I am trying to set them inside the same function using variables, just to do some other "pipes" and concactenate them again with other information. But I got this behavior. Basically, what I am trying to do is:

```
    > for i in $(ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f 3 | cut -d: -f2) ; do ping -c1 $i | grep packet | a=`echo $i-$(cut -d,
    -f3)` | echo $a; done  
4  
4  
4  
4
```

As you can see, it returns the number 4 for each iteration.

If I just remove the variable attribution, I get the output I was expecting to set in variable 'a' at first place:

```
> for i in $(ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f 3 | cut -d: -f2) ; do ping -c1 $i | grep packet | echo $i-$(cut -d, -f3); done
10.0.2.15- 0% packet loss
192.168.0.2- 0% packet loss
10.0.2.100- 0% packet loss
127.0.0.1- 0% packet loss
```

- Why am I getting number 4 as output in first function code execution?
- How can I set a variable inside the same function and echo it again after some pipelines? Is that possible?

Best regards !

Comment: Can you show the output of `ifconfig` ? that pipeline is really not needed.

Comment: @Jetchisel it is just a regular ifconfig output. I am doing that | grep to get just the address related part.

Comment: what system/os is that `regular ifconfig` output then?

Comment: This is an example. I am just cutting the address part that I am interest to:

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00 
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:45168 (44.1 KiB)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  for i in $(...) ; do ... | a=`...` | echo $a; done
> ```
>
> Why am I getting number 4 as output in first function code execution?

Because `` a=`...` `` and `echo $a` are executed in different subshells / subprocesses. `a=1; a=3 | echo $a` will print `1` in any shell. There's no way to pass a variable from a subshell to its parent.

> How can I set a variable inside the same function and echo it again after some pipelines? Is that possible?

No. Unless you set it in the main script, before the pipeline.

Comment: Very good explanation. I tried something: # a=1;a=2;a=3 | echo $a (outputs 2).
So, It got second 'a' value in the output, and not the first one. @pizdelect

Comment: The `;` has lower precedence than `|`. You're not fooling the parser by huddling the assignments close together -- the parser will still group it as `a=1;  a=2;  { a=3 | echo $a; }`, not as `{ a=1; a=2; a=3; } | echo $a`. Just like `4+4 / 2` is `6` not `4`

Comment: Got  your point ! It should be considered precedence order in command execution by Bash

Answer (score 0):

If you restructure the last part of the pipeline using `sed` I think you can get what you want. The `sed` script matches the whole standard input and replaces it with the value of `$i` followed by `-` and the third field of your `ping` output (from stdin). For example,

```
$ for i in $(ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f3 | cut -d: -f2); do \
    ping -c1 $i | grep packet | cut -d, -f3 | sed "s/\(.*\)/$i - \\1/"; \
done
123.145.167.189 -  0% packet loss
127.0.0.1 -  0% packet loss
```

Comment: Hello. I am able to print it, just cutting the variable attribution. What I was trying to do, in fact, was save that to a variable so I could concactenate with other values a few pipelines after, to make all of that working in a single function...

Comment: @JohnC in that case you might want to turn this into a shell script and use temporary files (see `mktemp`) to save pieces of data that you want in each part of the pipeline for use at the end.